# Como criar uma tag dentro de outra tag, mais texto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar em JavaScript uma tag **p** e dentro dela duas tags **a**, e mais o texto como esta no HTML abaixo, porem não estou conseguindo.

Eu consegui criar a tag **p** e dentro dela a tag **a**, mas não consigo adicionar o texto, e nem a outra tag **a**.

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Termos de Uso</a> e
    <a href="#">Políticas de Privacidade</a> deste site
  </p>
</div>
```

Meu código:

```
  var newEl = document.createElement('p')
  let newA = document.createElement('a');

  let newText = document.createTextNode('Termos de Uso');
  let position = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    
  newA.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
  newA.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

  newA.appendChild(newText);
  newEl.appendChild(newA);
    
  position.appendChild(newEl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer adicionar texto onde? em `p` ou em `a`?. Não da de adicionar duas vezes o mesmo filho.

No caso, se quiser adicionar duas `a`, tem que criar dois elementos `a`:

```js
var newEl = document.createElement('p')
let newA = document.createElement('a');
let newB = document.createElement('a');

let newText = document.createTextNode('Termos de Uso');
let position = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

newA.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
newA.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
newA.appendChild(newText);

let newTextB = document.createTextNode('Texto B');
newB.setAttribute("href", "https://google.com");
newB.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
newB.appendChild(newTextB);

newEl.appendChild(newA);
newEl.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

newEl.appendChild(newB);


position.appendChild(newEl);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>


<script>
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não consegue adicionar a outra âncora porque no seu código JavaScript só se criou uma.

E o texto “a parte” também não foi criado. Para criar o texto, você pode utilizar a função `document.createTextNode` e depois fazer o *append*.

Mais ou menos assim:

```js
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root');

const p = document.createElement('p');

const a1 = document.createElement('a');
a1.textContent = 'Termos de Uso';
a1.href = '#';

const text1 = document.createTextNode(' e ');

const a2 = document.createElement('a');
a2.textContent = 'Políticas de Privacidade';
a2.href = '#';

const text2 = document.createTextNode(' deste site');

// Iterar sobre cada um dos elementos e fazer o append no parágrafo.
[a1, text1, a2, text2].forEach((node) => p.appendChild(node));

// Append do parágrafo na div raiz:
rootDiv.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Repare que se o elemento só tiver texto (como é o caso das duas âncoras, você pode utilizar a propriedade `textContent` diretamente).

Mas claro, se você souber que o HTML que está inserindo é seguro (isto é, não vem diretamente do usuário), pode criar toda a estrutura diretamente via `innerHTML`, assim:

```js
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root');

// Garanta que esta string venha de fontes confiáveis (i.e. não venha do usuário).
rootDiv.innerHTML = `
  <p>
    <a href="#">Termos de Uso</a> e
    <a href="#">Políticas de Privacidade</a> deste site
  </p>
`;
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Só tem que tomar cuidado com isso para não inserir código vindo de fontes sem o próprio tratamento, já que isso se configura como vetor de [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), uma grave vulnerabilidade.